# The right way to type hint a Coroutine function?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine, type-hinting

I cannot wrap my head around type hinting a `Coroutine`. As far as I understand, when we declare a function like so:

```
async def some_function(arg1: int, arg2: str) -> list:
    ...
```

we **effectively** declare a function, which returns a coroutine, which, when awaited, returns a list. So, the way to type hint it would be:

```
f: Callable[[int, str], Coroutine[???]] = some_function
```

But `Coroutine` generic type has 3 arguments! We can see it if we go to the `typing.py` file:

```
...
Coroutine = _alias(collections.abc.Coroutine, 3)
...
```

There is also `Awaitable` type, which **logically** should be a parent of `Coroutine` with only one generic parameter (the return type, I suppose):

```
...
Awaitable = _alias(collections.abc.Awaitable, 1)
...
```

So maybe it would be more or less correct to type hint the function this way:

```
f: Callable[[int, str], Awaitable[list]] = some_function
```

Or is it?

So, basically, the questions are:

1. Can one use `Awaitable` instead of `Coroutine` in the case of type hinting an `async def` function?
2. What are the correct parameters for the `Coroutine` generic type and what are its use-cases?

Comment: 1. See an example of type hinting of async function in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#callable). So, you're doing it right.
2. Check [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Coroutine) with an example. [See also](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#coroutine-objects)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Awaitable) state:

> `Coroutine` objects and instances of the `Coroutine` ABC are all instances of the `Awaitable` ABC.

And for the `Coroutine` type:

> A generic version of `collections.abc.Coroutine`. The variance and order of type variables correspond to those of `Generator`.

`Generator` in turn has the signature `Generator[YieldType, SendType, ReturnType]`. So if you want to preserve that type information, use `Coroutine`, otherwise `Awaitable` should suffice.

Answer (score 13):

The `Coroutine` type takes the same signature as the `Generator` type:

`Generator[YieldType, SendType, ReturnType]`

Since the result of an unawaited call to a coroutine is an awaitable (it can be used in an `await` expression), it can be type hinted with:

`Awaitable[ReturnType]`

Example:

```
async def some_function(arg1: int, arg2: str) -> List[str]:
    return ['foo']

coro: Awaitable[List[str]] = some_function(1, 'bar')
result = await coro
print(result)
# prints ['foo']
```

However, for type hinting a coroutine, I do not find either of these useful on their own.
Instead, I opt for something similar to what you stated in your last example:

```
def return_coro() -> Callable[[int, str], Awaitable[List[str]]]:
    async def some_function(arg1: int, arg2: str) -> List[str]:
        return ['foo']
    return some_function
```

Note mypy will get upset if you try to pass this into a function which explicitly expects a Coroutine (such as asyncio.run()).

Answer (score 2):

The corresponding type for a coroutine function

```
async def some_function(arg1: A, arg2: B, /) -> R: ...
```

is `Callable[[A, B], Coroutine[Any, Any, R]]`. [The return type is the third argument of `Coroutine`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Coroutine); the other arguments are implementation details of the `async` framework used so `Any` is appropriate for portability and compatibility.
This can simply be checked by using [`typing.reveal_type(some_function)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.reveal_type) with a type checker. For example, MyPy reveals (using its `Callable` shorthand notation):

```
Revealed type is "def [A, B, R] (A`-1, B`-2) -> typing.Coroutine[Any, Any, R`-3]"
```

If the full parameter specification, documentation, or simply no reliance on `Coroutine` is desired, a [`Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) with `async def __call__` can be used instead:

```
class SomeFunctionType(Protocol):
    async def __call__(self, arg1: A, arg2: B, /) -> R: ...
```

---

While it is often possible to use `Awaitable[R]` instead of `Coroutine[Any, Any, R]` this should be avoided when explicitly describing coroutine functions: An `Awaitable[R]` only expresses the *limited feature set* that `Coroutine[Any, Any, R]` shares with *all other* awaitables. Various important `async` framework functions, such as [`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html#asyncio.run) or [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task), rely on the full feature set and thus only work with actual `Coroutine`s.

As a rule of thumb, use `Awaitable` to be lenient with parameters accepted but use `Coroutine` to be precise for objects provided.