# How to fix "Coroutine object is not callable" type hint warning?

Tags: python, types, type-hinting, coroutine

I'm having troubles with type hinting in my async pytest fixtures.
Fixture 1:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
async def create_raw_user(asyncpg_pool) -> Callable[[str, str, str], Awaitable[None]]:
    async def create_raw_user(email: str, name: str, password: str) -> None:
        auth = AuthHandler()
        hashed_password = auth.get_password_hash(password)
        async with asyncpg_pool.acquire() as connection:
            return await connection.execute(
                "INSERT INTO users (email, name, password, registered_at, auth0_registered) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"
                % (email, name, hashed_password, datetime.utcnow(), False)
            )

    return create_raw_user
```

Fixture 2:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
async def create_user_instance(create_raw_user) -> Callable[[str, str, str], Awaitable[dict[str, Any]]]:
    async def create_user_instance(email: str = "test@email.com",
                                   name: str = "ilya",
                                   password: str = "password123") -> dict[str, Any]:
        await create_raw_user(email=email, name=name, password=password)
        return {
            "email": email,
            "name": name,
            "password": password
        }

    return create_user_instance
```

The Pycharm warning occurs in the second fixture and in tests functions:
[image]

[[image]

Tried to follow the recommendations from these sources, but it didn't really help:
[The right way to type hint a Coroutine function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73240620/the-right-way-to-type-hint-a-coroutine-function)
https://github.com/python/typing/issues/424